# Asymptotic Running Time

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

```
for i = 1....n do
  j=1
  while j*j<=i do j=j+1
```

I need to find the asysmptotic running time in theta(?) notation.
I found that

```
3(1) + 5(2) + 7(3) + 9(4).....+.......
```

and I tried to find the answere using the summation by parts.
but I couldn't....Can anyone explain or give me some clue.

Comment: could you explain why the inner loop is theta(sqrt(n))????

Comment: refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The overall complexity of the code snippet can be rewritten as:

```
for i = 1 to n        
do for j = 1 to floor(sqrt(n))
```

Hence, we get the overall complexity as **sigma** of `sqrt(i)` when `i` varies from 1 to `n`.
Unfortunately, there is no elementary formula for a series of sum of square roots, so we have to depend on **integration**.

Integration of `sqrt(i)` with limits would be `n sqrt(n)` (Ignoring constant factors).

Hence, the overall time complexity of the loop is **n sqrt(n)**.

Comment: Great answer! One small thing to point out maybe is why O(floor(sqrt(n)) == O(sqrt(n)). floor is basically a constant: floor(sqrt(n) = sqrt(n) + c. So it drops out.

Comment: I used `floor()` because `sqrt(n)` will be a float, and I wanted to round it off down to the nearest integer because `j` can never be greater than `sqrt(n)`, hence `j` can never be greater than `floor(sqrt(j))` too. Thanks, @starmole.

Comment: A thanks would be best appreciated with an effort to make the grey tick turn green! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you may proceed methodically:

[image]

To obtain theta, you should find out the formula of the summation of floored square root of i (which is not obvious).

To be safe, I chose **Big Oh**.